# Stop "member has protected access" message

Tags: php, phpstorm

I'm not sure if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong but consider the following code:

**ParentClass.php**

```
<?php
class ParentClass {    
    public static function getA() {
        $obj = new ChildClass();
        return $obj->a();
    }
}
```

**ChildClass.php**

```
<?php
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    protected function a() {
        return "a";
    }
}
```

However PhpStorm is showing an error in `ParentClass.php` on line `return $obj->a();` saying:

> Member has protected access

[The manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) that:

> Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inheriting **and parent** classes.

Is this a PhpStorm bug? If so is there a way to disable this error (for affected files ideally but globally would also do in a pinch).

Sidenote: I'm not discussing whether this is coding practices that should be followed but the actual problem is deep within legacy code I am very reluctant to modify and is causing my project navigation bar to fill up with squiggly red lines all over to indicate errors (which are not actual errors).

Comment: `$obj` should be `$this`.

Comment: I think your child and parent classes are switched

Comment: @BenM `$obj` is correct. That function is static so `$this` doesn't really mean anything

Comment: In which case, use `self::`. You're trying to access a protected method of an **object**, PHP doesn't know anything about the parent class for `$obj`.

Comment: What's throwing the error? Your IDE? This executes fine for me without errors.

Comment: @BenM The code is correct as far as PHP is concerned check :https://3v4l.org/HsrD3

Comment: @Kisaragi yes this is about PHP Storm flagging that line as an error

Comment: Running php storm 2016.1.2 with PHP 7.XX as the interpreter and no errors here, but there's a chance at some point I've disabled those types of errors ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Kisaragi I'm using 2018.2 so it would be interesting to know if this is a regression or if there's an actual way to disable this error.

Comment: @apokryfos I was able to get the same error message by removing the extension of the parent class. I was able to make the error go away by lowering the code inspection settings under settings > editor > inspections, or right clicking on the high light and changing there.

Comment: Clarification: right click on right most scroll bar > select customize highlight level

Comment: Customising the highlight level does indeed work (and it's on a per file basis as well so that's a plus).

Comment: If I understand this correctly -- it's pretty much https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11263

Comment: @LazyOne does look like it.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this with phpStorm 2018.1.

Either this is a bug in phpStorm or this is just a warning by phpStorm because even tho it is possible in PHP to access a protected member this way, one should be warned because it is a thing you should probably avoid.

Because it is confusing, to access a protected/private member outside the scope.

The explanation is here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visibility-other-objects

> Objects of the same type will have access to each others private and
>   protected members **even though they are not the same instances**. This is
>   because the implementation specific details are already known when
>   inside those objects.

Both of your classes are instanceof `ParentClass` so both can access each others protected and private members.

As LazyOne pointed out, there actually are bugs in phpStorm concerning this and similiar effects: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11263

Comment: OTOH, the requested access is not from an **object** of the same type. It is at the **class** level (its in a static). Or perhaps the problem is that *"of the same type"* really means *"within code of that class"*. So within `ChildClass` there would be no warning. I'd classify it not as a code bug, but as a documentation bug: doc doesn't quite say what its trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

The ParentClass cannot access the child's a() method because it the parent class does not have that function, it is not inheriting that function, and it's protected so you can't call it from outside it's class or a class derived from ChildClass.

If you had a() defined in the ParentClass, then you could make the function getA() in the ChildClass and then it would have access to a()

Comment: [The manual says](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inheriting **and parent** classes.

Comment: @apokryfos I believe the "and" between inheriting and parent is a typo. It should be "inheriting parent classes".

Comment: @ChrisBornhoft - that would be illogical. A **parent** class is the **opposite** of an **inheriting** class.

Comment: Illogical would be inheriting a child class, you can very much inherit a parent class.